# Can't launch a simple Pentaho job from Java due to missing artifact in recommended Jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to launch a simple Pentaho (Kettle/Spoon) Job (.ktr) from Java. I have my project dependencies configured with graddle so in theory I only have to add the pentaho-kettle and pentaho-big-data-plugin modules as dependencies for me to launch the job.

The problem is that the pentaho-big-data-plugin module comes with an error: It does not contain the jsf-api:1.1 jar, so the project fails to compile.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-core', version: '7.1.0.0-12'
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-dbdialog', version: '7.1.0.0-12'
compile group: 'pentaho-kettle', name: 'kettle-engine', version: '7.1.0.0-12'
compile 'pentaho:pentaho-big-data-plugin:7.1.0.0-12'
```

Here is the error IntelliJ provides when trying to compile:

> Warning:***root project 'tfg-j-hipster-app': Web Facets/Artifacts
>   will not be configured properly** Details:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException:
>   Could not find jsf-api.jar (javax.faces:jsf-api:1.1). Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.1/jsf-api-1.1.jar*

Here are the repositories I am searching within:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }

    // My repositories
    maven { url 'http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni' }
}
```

My Pentaho version is 7.1.0.0-12.

Comment: For such questions, include the Pentaho version you are using.

Comment: It is 7.1.0.0-12. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the compiled bundle from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/), you should get all the needed jar the Pentaho version you are using.

Now, as far as the jsf-api is concerned, the 4th response on a google `find jar for jsf-api` was https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api. Please find the appropriate version.

However, I wonder how a runtime error can prevent your class to compile. Your 
bug maybe else were.

Comment: "If you download the compiled bundle from SourceForge, you should get all the needed jar the Pentaho version you are using." - I did. However, I am trying to manage it all with gradle from the nexus repository (https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/).

Comment: "Now, as far as the jsf-api is concerned, ..." - I know, I already have downloaded the jar I need (jsf-api-1.1)  and I tried compiling it from the local jar with gradle (compile files('/home/catalin/Descargas/jsf-api.jar'))... but I get the same error.  

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileOnly'.
> Could not find jsf-api.jar (javax.faces:jsf-api:1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/jsf-api/1.1/jsf-api-1.1.jar

Comment: I have to test: Where did you get the code from? https://github.com/pentaho/big-data-plugin? svn://source.pentaho.org/svnkettleroot/Kettle/branches/4.4.0?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/?source=typ_redirect From here